# String in String.Format({0:N}) Could not find any space inside string

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm faced with the following problem - I format a string from a textbox

```
stringValue = String.Format(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"), "{0:N}",
                                                            result);
```

Everything seems OK, but when I try to find spaces inside this string, all methods return null or -1 like spaces are absent in the string, but numbers are split by spaces in my textbox! Why are the spaces not found? If I use any other string format - I could find any symbol in the string. What's the problem here? Who knows?

Comment: Post the code you're using to attempt to find spaces?

Comment: What spaces are you looking for? What is the input and output here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there *isn't* a space, in terms of U+0020 (the normal ASCII space).

What you'll get in the output for the thousands separator is U+00A0, which is a non-breaking space. (At least, that's what I've seen.)

It's not clear what you're using this for, but perhaps you need to change your code to detect any whitespace rather than `' '`.

Comment: Now I do in that way:
string input = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
if (input.Contains(" "))
How I must modify code to detect any whitespaces?

Comment: @Denis: It may be simplest to use a regular expression matching `\s`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I need to know is there any whitespace in the caret index position. Any known method could not determine this.

Comment: @Denis: I don't understand - the regular expression check would be the same as your `Contains` check... it would check for the presence of any whitespace within the text. Why do you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: As I wrote earlier I need to know the position of that whitespace. Regular expression does not give me such info. I will use char.isNumber() method for this. Coul you please answer another small question - why I cannot convert string in this format to double like this - result = System.Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); but only this way - Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out result);???

Comment: @Denis: Does `Match.Index` not do what you want? As for your other question - it's culture-sensitive, and in the ToDouble version you're using InvariantCulture.

Comment: thanks for the info about regular expressions. I didnt know that.

Comment: If you refuse to use a regex, I guess you could call `Char.IsWhiteSpace` on every character.  Looking at the .Net reference source, that's how `String.Trim` is implemented.